# printing . before every character in a string

Tags: python, string

I have a string and it's `"java is fun for sure"` and i want to print

1. delete every vowel letters(aeiou)
2. print a "." before every character

so the out come would be like `".j.v. .s. .f.n. .f.r. .s.r"`

I have tried this

```
s = str(input())
s.translate({ord(i): None for i in 'aeiou '})
```

the outcome is `"jvsfnfrsr"` but i don't know how to print "." before the letters.
Some help would be awesome! I'm sure this is a very simple issue, but for some reason i cannot come up with it!

Thx in advance! :)

Comment: input() returns a string - no need to str() it.

Comment: Change `None` for `"."`: `s.translate({ord(i): "." for i in 'aeiou '})`

Comment: @Emer that would replace the vowels with . NOT put a . before eack consonant:  "lipstick" -> "l.pst.ck"

Comment: Ooops. I misunderstood what you'd want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 3-param version of [maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) to create the needed translation dictionary. Use the [the `sep` param of `print(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) to place the `.`:

```
s  = "java is fun for sure"
s1 = s.translate(str.maketrans("", "", "aeiou")) # AEIOU are kept as is
print("", *s.translate(str.maketrans("", "", "aeiou")), sep=".")
```

or in short:

```
print("",*"java is fun for sure".translate(str.maketrans("", "", "aeiou")),sep=".")
```

The * before the string-var decomposes the string into its letters:

```
print(*"abc", sep = "#") # == print("a","b","c", sep = "#")
```

Output:

```
.j.v. .s. .f.n. .f.r. .s.r
```

If you need the resulting string you can use str.join():

```
s2 = '.' + '.'.join(s1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

s = str(input())
s = s.translate({ord(i): None for i in 'aeiouAEIOU'})
print(re.sub('([^\s])', r'.\1', s))
```

Input: `"java is fun for sure"`

Output: `".j.v .s .f.n .f.r .s.r"`

A solution using regex

Answer (score 1):

What about this? It retains capitalised letters also.

```py
vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
tmp = ''.join([char for char in str1 if char not in vowels])
final = ''.join(['.'+char for char in tmp])
```

Comment: `final = '.' + '.'.join(tmp)` would work as well ;)